# How do I convert 3 Lists in a combined array of 3 members in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a noob in Python 3, I'm coming from Java and javascript.

How can I go from

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

to

```
x = [ ['a', 1, 'red'], ['b', 2, 'green'], ['c', 3, 'blue'] ]
```

in an easy way, without using some loop (while/for/map) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `zip` builtin was made for. `zip` takes an arbitrary number of iterables and returns tuples with items from corresponding indices.

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
>>> list(map(list, zip(a, b, c)))
[['a', 1, 'red'], ['b', 2, 'green'], ['c', 3, 'blue']]
```

The tuples `zip` generates are explicitly converted to lists here because you requested lists. If there's no particular reason for having lists instead of tuples, just use

```
>>> list(zip(a, b, c))
[('a', 1, 'red'), ('b', 2, 'green'), ('c', 3, 'blue')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all lists have the same length, you can use list comprehension

x = [[a[i],b[i],c[i]] for i in range(len(a)) ]

this will result in

[['a', 1, 'red'], ['b', 2, 'green'], ['c', 3, 'blue']]

Answer (score 1):

```
def combine_list(*args):
     return map(list, args)

final = list(combine_list(a,b,c))
```

It will be like:

> [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], ['red', 'green', 'blue']]

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned **"in an easy way, without using some loop (while/for/map)"**

This was the easiest approach I could think of:

Firstly, define a, b, c that contains data, p, q, r as temporary list and an empty list x to store final output. Simple use append function of list sequentially to append a, b and c to x. Print x and you will have a list of lists without using any for-loop! But at the stake of extra memory and duck typing.

```
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    b = [1, 2, 3]
    c = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

    p = []
    q = []
    r = []

    x = []

    p.append(a[0])
    p.append(b[0])
    p.append(c[0])

    q.append(a[1])
    q.append(b[1])
    q.append(c[1])

    r.append(a[2])
    r.append(b[2])
    r.append(c[2])

    x.append(p)
    x.append(q)
    x.append(r)

    print(x)
```